# how to retrieve the num value from image src?

Tags: javascript

I have a src information from a image like "/images/slide1.jpg" just I want to swap the slide1 to slide2, any one give me the right way to find and replace img src ?

Comment: Just use something like `url.substring(13, 1);`.

Comment: That will not work if more than 9 images are used.

Comment: That's correct, I thought 3gwebtrain only used slide1 and slide2. You could instead use `url.split(".")[0].substring(13);` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('image id goes here').
    src = '/images/slide' + number + '.jpg';
```

If you want to get the number, then in your particular case, this would work:

```
number = document.getElementById('image id goes here').
    src.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Comment: i am getting the path like this: http://someserver.frontend.london.com/images/slide1/slide.jpg, as well the path may vary from place to place, so i want to extract the path without file name and i need to set new file name, for that how can i retrive the path and file name alone?

Comment: Maybe asking a new question would do that well, as your question is very different now.

Comment: i am working for a slide show, there is 2 buttons, one is next, another one is previous. while next button clicked, my current image need to change to next one. in case they clicked previous button my previous image has to load. i have 10+ images, each image name is like slide1, slide2, slide3 like so. to do that i am asking

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you using regex. It splits out the src into base, filename and extension (as well as picking up the last number in the filename as being the number you wish to increment)

```
var img = document.getElementById('myimage'),  // image element
    regex = /^(.+\/)([^\/]+)(\d+)(\..+)$/,     // parsing regex
    matches = regex.exec(img.src);             // execute regex

// Just to be tidy - getting the matches and parsing the number
var props = {
    'base' : matches[1],
    'filename' : matches[2],
    'filenumber' : parseInt(matches[3],10),
    'extension' : matches[4] 
};

// Create the next image string
var nextImage = props.base + props.filename + (props.filenumber+1) + props.extension; 

// Set the next image
img.src = nextImage;

alert('Set image to ' + nextImage);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/JKtXd/

Comment: while i go double digit number in my file name, it take only the last number, example in case slide.10.jpg means it takes only '0' instead of 10.

Comment: I am very sorry, what you give the code exactly working fine. thanks for your kind help. your the guru in javascript. if you have your twitter id, pls give me, let me follow. thanks once again.